# Show/hide buttons disappear

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#incl").toggle(500);
    $(this).hide();
    $("button").text('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
#incl {
  display: none;
}
.incl {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 800;
  background-color: #00689C;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: -197px -10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("#incl").toggle(500);
      $(this).hide();
      $("button").text('hide');
    });
  });
</script>

<button>INCLUDES</button>
<div id="incl">
  <ul class="incl">
    <li>bla bla bla</li>
    <li>bla ti bla</li>
    <li>bla bla</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I run this scenario the button disappears.
what I would like to happen is the button that echo "includes" must echo "hide" instead
I'm trying to make a button that shows item details and then hide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. Using `$(this).text()` (without any parameters) will get the current text of the button. I store it, and then swap based on what it's currently set to, and toggle it between "HIDE" or "INCLUDES".

You can also do any of the following:

- Create two buttons, and two click handlers. 1st show button will show the "hide" button, show the content, and hide the "show" button. The 2nd hide button will do the opposite.
- Set a boolean if the content is being shown (outside the function). Then, one if/else statement will determine if it's set or not:

```
if ( contentShown )
{
    $('#content').hide();
    $('#button').text('Show');
}
else
{
    $('#content').show();
    $('#button').text('Hide');
}
contentShown = !contentShown;  //Invert contentShown (Set it to true if false, or false if true)
```

Please note, I commented out the margin/position in the css to show it in the snippet below.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
      $("#incl").toggle(500);
      var currentText = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(currentText == "INCLUDES" ? "HIDE" : "INCLUDES");
    });
  });
```

```css
#incl {
  display: none;
}
.incl {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  z-index: 800;
  background-color: #00689C;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  /*margin: -197px -10px 0 0;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">INCLUDES</button>
<div id="incl">
  <ul class="incl">
    <li>bla bla bla</li>
    <li>bla ti bla</li>
    <li>bla bla</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @WilloBOoM If you want multiple buttons, you need to reference the other buttons in your function. Your example only showed one button, so I made the code to work with that one button. If you'd like to edit your question, I'd be happy to help with making the necessary changes to fixing it to work with two buttons.

Comment: Meta discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335690/moderator-deleting-comments-in-the-middle-of-a-discussion).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for which your button disappears is this line:

```
$(this).hide();
```

inside the click handler.

Moreover, your class *incl* has *margin: -197px -10px 0 0;*, this means you need to adjust this when showing the content.

In your click handler you may test the button text in order to decide the right action to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("#incl").toggle(500);
    var sign = '-';
    var txt = 'INCLUDES';
    //
    // According to the button text you can decide
    // the next button text and if you need
    // to correct the margings of your element
    // adding or removing for the margins.
    //
    if (this.textContent == 'INCLUDES') {
      sign = '+';
      txt = 'hide';
    }
    $('.incl').animate({"margin-top": sign + "=197px", "margin-right": sign + "=10px"}, 500)
    $("button").text(txt);
  });
});
```

```css
#incl {
  display: none;
}

.incl {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 800;
  background-color: #00689C;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: -197px -10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>INCLUDES</button>
<div id="incl">
    <ul class="incl">
        <li>bla bla bla</li>
        <li>bla ti bla</li>
        <li>bla bla</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```